# DXF created by QGIS crashes Autocad

Tags: qgis, autocad, dxf

This is slightly complicated. I have a dxf created by autocad which seems to have been corrupted. It will not open in AutoCAD. However, it opens in QGIS.

I tried selecting the file in QGIS and saving as DXF. however when i try to open it in AutoCAD it cause AutoCAD to crash.

this is a similar question to [Exported DXF from QGIS won't open in AutoCAD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/i-exported-a-dxf-from-qgis-but-it-wont-open-in-autocad) but it was not adequately answered.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What version of AutoCAD are you using?

Comment: AutoCAD 2013...its the free student version.

Comment: The question seems to be answered in the comments to http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37164/187. It's probably a GDAL bug and should be reported.

Comment: A kind of an answer but not. basically it cant. but cool.

Answer (score 1):

something that i use for exporting files from qgis to autocad lt2013 is via dgn files.
try exporting the dxf in qgis as dgn microstation, autocad may load the dgn without crashing