# Export all visible layers in map view window to DXF (as one)

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

I'm looking to find a way of exporting all that is visible in the map view window to a dxf file. That is to say, multiple features from multiple layers, all at once. Can this be done?

Comment: You will have to merge the data sources together to export as one DXF.

Comment: So, merge all required shapefiles into one?

Comment: yes if all your features are lines they can be merged into one shapefile then export to dxf.

Comment: Just by way of an asside and not to try steal the tunder here...but eporting to dxf straight from QGIS has always failed for me. You will need to use grass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Mapperz answer above. So what i would do is to select and save each area which you wish to be converted into a dxf seperately. Do this by using the select tool.

Once you have selected the area right click on the layer and select save selection as.

As i said i would recommend creating an entire new directory (folder) with all your selected data in.

Then once you have all saved out, go to vecto - data management tools - merge shapefiles to one.  Select the directory, decide if they are polygons, polylines or points. and save new file.

Open this new file in Grass and export as dxf via Grass.  Note that you will have to unsupress file extensions and give the file a .dxf extension in order for it to work.

See my answer on this question for a walkthrough on how to do it.

[Exported DXF from QGIS won't open in AutoCAD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/i-exported-a-dxf-from-qgis-but-it-wont-open-in-autocad)

Comment: Thank you for your kind input, Gerald and @Mapperz. It's a slightly lengthy workaround, which is a shame, given as even older programs like ProPrinter provide this feature at the click of one button. I'd love to be able to create a plugin to do this, but don't have the know-how, sadly :-(